# Inefficiently Placing Circles in a Square

Tags: geometry

Let's say you are given n number of circles all having a radius of integer r. Using n and r, find the length of the largest square all of the circles could occupy without leaving room for more circles?

Comment: Just an idea as I happen to go around: have you tried it this way? What is the longest line segment that you can cover with $n$ intervals of length $2r$ such that there is no room for more intervals?

Comment: That's what I used on my previous implementation. It works, but it is not optimal for all values of n, it is only optimal when n's square root is a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can be no more circles, then essentially each point inside the square must have a circle center at distance less than $2r$ from it. Otherwise it could be the center of an additional circle. So instead of packing inefficiently with circles of radius $r$, you are essentially covering with circles of radius $2r$. You'l have to make slight adjustments at the rim, because you can take the maximal covered square and add $r$ in all directions to adapt it to your problem, but that's just a cosmetic correction. [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/) has [circles covering squares](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovsqu/) for up to $n=12$ circles.

Comment: Clever. Thanks!

Comment: Link in the answer seems to be dead. Looking at a [copy in the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190417075723/https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html), the new URL with the same content seems to be: https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak, I've updated the links.